# gcc/g++ not producing debug symbols for variables

Tags: gcc, g++

I have tried both gcc and g++, for each of them using `-g`, `-O0`, `-Og`, and various combinations thereof, even `gcc -g -Og -c main.c -O0 -g -g -g -g`. I do not get symbols for my variables.

I have made a reduced test program with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void aFunction() { printf("?\n"); }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int intVariable = 0;
    printf("argc = %d, intVariable = %d\n", argc, intVariable);
    return 0;
}
```

Even with that code, compiled with either gcc or g++, using all manner of -g/-O0/-Og, also trying -c to make sure the linking phase wasn't stripping it out, still, in either the .o or the .out file I can see the functions but not the variables.

I am checking with `nm main.o` (or `nm a.out` when omitting the -c). The output includes `aFunction` and `main`, but it does not include `argc` and not `intVariable`.

I have read over so many questions/answers/posts/articles/etc. trying to figure out why gcc/g++ are not producing debug symbols for my variables, but I cannot fix this. Most sources just mention `-g`, `-O0`, `-Og`, and avoiding `-s` and compile-optimization.

I need the symbols for debugging in gdb. If I do `gdb a.out` then `break main`, let it run and break, then `bt` to confirm I'm in `main` and `print argc` or `print intVariable` I get the "No symbol "argc" in current context." since the symbols for them aren't present.

When running in gdb, I also get the message "Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-..." I mention it here for completeness, but I don't think that is related since, if I understand correctly, that would only be necessary if I want to debug into lower level glibc-specific code. Correct me if I'm wrong.

This is not the first time I've tried to fix this, and this attempt just wasted a bunch of time again. It would be great if I could use gdb properly.

How do you troubleshoot missing symbols from compiled code?

I'm using gcc 4.9.2. I've tested on a couple of versions of Red Hat on a few different computers. I do not have the ability to change the versions of anything or to install anything here at work, but I can probably try different versions of gcc or operating systems while I'm at home.

Chris Dodds points out that perhaps it is my version of GDB rather than my version or usage or GCC. Doing `gdb --version` produces output beginning with: `GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-83.el6)`.

Comment: What version of gdb are you using?  gcc4.9 usually produces dwarf v4 debug symbols that older versions of gdb can't understand, though usually you'll get an error from gdb about being unable to read the debug symbols.

Comment: `gdb --version` outputs: GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-83.el6)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later (more irrelevant license information here)
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".

Comment: And `gcc --version` provides 4.9.2

Comment: That's a pretty ancient version of gdb.  I've used 7.8.1 successfully with gcc 4.9.  7.12 appears to be the most recent gdb version.

Comment: I will see if I can get GDB updated. Hopefully that's all the problem is. I'll report back on that if/when (and that's a big if/when) I can get someone to update GDB. I've asked before to have it updated without success, but since it might actually be causing problems now I'll try to move it up the chain. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nm` normally does not show debugging symbols.  You can try with the `-a` or `--debug-syms` options to get it to display them.

For a better display of debugging symbols, you can try `dwarfdump`

The most likely explanation is that you are getting debug symbols in the executable, but gdb is unable to read them because your distro has an old(er) version of gdb that doesn't understand the dwarf version produced by new(er) versions of gcc. The solution is generally to update gdb to the latest version (may require building from source on some distros).

Comment: Thank you. Some of the other answers/posts I've read suggested using `nm` to verify that the symbols were/weren't present, but the requirement for `-a`/`--debug-syms` was not mentioned that I saw. So I just added `--debug-syms` and it shows more data, including entries with `N` in the second column, but nothing for `argc`/`intVariable`.

Comment: Since local variables are not at a specific address (they're in a register or in a stack fram), there are no symobls for them directly.  Instead, the .debug_info section contains the info about such symbols.  Use `dwarfdump` to actually decode the contents of the various debugging sections.

Comment: So, are you suggesting that this is now intended behavior of GCC, or the Linux debug format, or whoever you want to blame? I should no longer be able to easily see local variable symbols, and if I run in GDB I should no longer be able to print local variables, not even if I have compiled with `-g` and either `-O0` or `-O0`? I was assuming that what I'm experiencing is abnormal and was hoping for confirmation of that and preferably a fix. If this is now expected though, then we've taken a huge step backwards. Regardless, how do I fix it so I can debug properly in GDB?

Comment: By the way, I have encountered this on multiple computers. I think there are two different versions of Red Hat on the computers I've been using. I have not tested on other Linux distros or Windows.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you are getting debug symbols in the executable, but gdb is unable to read them because your distro has an old(er) version of gdb that doesn't understand the dwarf version produced by new(er) versions of gcc.  The solution is generally to update gdb to the latest version (may require building from source on some distros).

Comment: I have not been able to get GDB updated at work and so can't debug properly, but since you have stated in a separate comment that my gdb version is ancient, your guess here about the version being out of date seems plausible. If you update your answer to include that information, I will accept it.